# Microsoft Logo Animation v2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I updated my [animation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101172/microsoft-logo-animation) of the Microsoft's logo. It's available on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/lmenus/full/doEOoM/). Overall, I am quite satisfied with it now apart from one thing.

I cannot seem to figure out how to stop the animation so the logo looks correct. I tried setting the delay to 6000ms = 6s = length of the animation, but it looked way off. Right now it's set to 5900ms. Any tips on this?

Another thing I was wondering was, how would you make the YouTube video play after a certain amount of time, say when the text appears? Thanks!

```js
var playState = '-webkit-animation-play-state';

$(".boxes").css(playState, "running");
setTimeout(function() {
  $(".boxes").css(playState, "paused");
}, 5900);
```

```css
body {
  background: hsl(30, 20%, 20%);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.boxes {
  -webkit-animation: logo 6s 1 forwards;
  animation: logo 6s 1 forwards;
  position: absolute;
}

.box {
  -webkit-animation: scaling 1.5s cubic-bezier(.1,.95,.7,.8) 4;
  animation: scaling 1.5s cubic-bezier(.1,.95,.7,.8) 4;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.brand {
  -webkit-animation: fadein 2s ease 4.5s forwards;
  animation: fadein 2s ease 4.5s forwards;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin: 24px 0 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: -36px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 0;
}

.flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.intro {
  text-align: center;
}

.logo {
  -webkit-animation: moveLeft .5s linear 4.5s forwards;
  animation: moveLeft .5s linear 4.5s forwards;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  left: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.player {
  display:none;
}

#green {background: #7cbb00;}
#yellow {background: #ffbb00;}
#blue {background: #00a1f1;}
#red {background: #f65314;}

#animateGreen {animation-delay: 4.5s;}
#animateYellow {animation-delay: 3s;}
#animateBlue {animation-delay: 1.5s;}
#animateRed {animation-delay: 0s;}

@keyframes fadein {
  from {opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes logo {
  0% {left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: rotate(0deg)}
  25% {left: 50px; top: 0px; transform: rotate(-180deg)}
  50% {left: 50px; top: 50px; transform: rotate(-360deg)}
  75% {left: 0px; top: 50px; transform: rotate(-540deg)}
  100% {left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: rotate(-720deg)}
}

@keyframes moveLeft {
  from {padding-right: 0; left: 100px;}
  to {padding-right: 50px; left: 0;}
}

@keyframes scaling {
  0%, 100% {transform: scale(1)}
  50% {transform: scale(.5)}
}
```

```html
<head><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script></head>

<div class="flex">
  <div class="intro">
    <div class="logo">
      <div class="boxes" id="animateGreen">
        <div class="box" id="green">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" id="animateYellow">
        <div class="box" id="yellow">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" id="animateBlue">
        <div class="box" id="blue">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="boxes" id="animateRed">
        <div class="box" id="red">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brand">
      Microsoft
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/I3Ak5VgyEoc?autoplay=1" class="player"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery/JavaScript to stop the animation a better approach would be to specify a different animation for each box ending with them in the position you want.

[Example CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNwgWZ)

As for playing a YouTube video when the text appears, if you refer to the YouTube [API Docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference?csw=1#Playback_controls) it would be something like this in jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    //play the youtube video (#playerId) is the id of your youtube video element
    $('#playerId').get(0).playVideo();
} , 4500); //4500 is the delay in ms
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! I guess I was trying to be too efficient with not writing the extra animations. Thanks